# printing array only resulting in first value being printed into excel?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Assigning word document lines of text to an array to then print into an excel column. I want to print each item in array to it's own cell.

Currently, all the items are storying correctly into the array, but it's only printing the first item over and over `Action`

[image]

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ParaCopy()
    Dim wApp As Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("J:\Data Dictionary.docx", ReadOnly:=True)

    Dim wPara As Word.Paragraph
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    i = 0
    For Each wPara In wDoc.Paragraphs
        If wPara.Range.Words.Count > 1 Then
            ReDim Preserve arr(i)
            arr(i) = wPara.Range
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next wPara
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        [a1].Resize(UBound(arr) + 1) = arr
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

EDIT: Need to separate each block of text separated by a space (outlined in blue) to this [image: word doc] [image: output in excel]

Comment: `[a1].Resize(UBound(arr) + 1) = application.Transpose(arr)` you are putting a horizontal array in a vertical space.

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm getting a type mismatch error now

Comment: you data is probably too big for application.Transpose then.  Make the array a 2D array with one column and then paste that.

Comment: see my edit, just moved the counter in the If block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a 2D array with one column and load that:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ParaCopy()
    Dim wApp As Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("J:\Data Dictionary.docx", ReadOnly:=True)

    Dim wPara As Word.Paragraph
    Dim arr() As Variant
    ReDim arr(1 To wDoc.Paragraphs.Count, 1 To 1)
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    For Each wPara In wDoc.Paragraphs
        If wPara.Range.Words.Count > 1 Then
            arr(i, 1) = wPara.Range
            i = i + 1
        End If
        
    Next wPara

    [a1].Resize(UBound(arr) + 1) = arr
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Word Paragraphs to Excel Cells Using an Array

- The number of rows of the array is `wDoc.Paragraphs.Count` which may differ from `r` (the 'actual count') hence you have to use **`r`** with `Resize`, and not `wDoc.Paragraphs.Count` or `UBound(Data, 1)`.
- Don't forget to `Close` the `Document` and `Quit` the `App`.
- The first solution is early-bound and needs the library reference. When using it, just use
  `Set wApp = New Word.Application`.
- The second solution is late-bound and doesn't need the library reference. Also, it has been 'stripped off' the document and application variables (not necessary, you can declare them `As Object`).

```vb
Option Explicit

' e.g. Tools>References>Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library
Sub ParaCopy()
    
    Const FilePath As String = "J:\Data Dictionary.docx"
        
    Dim wApp As Word.Application: Set wApp = Set wApp = New Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document: Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(FilePath, , True)
    
    Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To wDoc.Paragraphs.Count, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim wPara As Word.Paragraph
    Dim r As Long
    
    For Each wPara In wDoc.Paragraphs
        If wPara.Range.Words.Count > 1 Then
            r = r + 1
            Data(r, 1) = wPara.Range
        End If
    Next wPara
    
    wDoc.Close False
    wApp.Quit
    
    [a1].Resize(r) = Data
    
End Sub

Sub ParaCopyNoReference()
    
    Const FilePath As String = "J:\Data Dictionary.docx"
        
    With CreateObject("Word.Application")
        With .Documents.Open(FilePath, , True)
            Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To .Paragraphs.Count, 1 To 1)
            Dim wPara As Object
            Dim r As Long
            For Each wPara In .Paragraphs
                If wPara.Range.Words.Count > 1 Then
                    r = r + 1
                    Data(r, 1) = wPara.Range
                End If
            Next wPara
            .Close False
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
    
    [a1].Resize(r) = Data
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Will try this out soon, thank you! I do have a quick question. Would it be difficult to have the data print like this: whenever there is a space between paragraphs, print data into new column?

Comment: Try to post two screenshots to show before and after or ask a new question and add one of the codes and describe in detail what is wrong.

Comment: So I just uploaded the two pics describing what I was looking to do. Is this a simple edit or should I post a new question?