# How to print array items from column A to multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

Im attempting to move a data dictionary in word over to excel. Every metric has lines with descriptors (summary, data source, etc...) between each metric in the dictionary (ms word) is a blank space to separate them. This code that I got help with places each line into it's own cell in column A of excel.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ParaCopy()
    Dim wApp As Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("J:\HRIS Team\Data Dictionary.docx", ReadOnly:=True)

    Dim wPara As Word.Paragraph
    Dim arr() As Variant
    ReDim arr(1 To wDoc.Paragraphs.Count, 1 To 1)
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    For Each wPara In wDoc.Paragraphs
        If wPara.Range.Words.Count > 1 Then
            arr(i, 1) = wPara.Range
            i = i + 1
        End If
        
    Next wPara
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        [a1].Resize(UBound(arr) + 1) = arr
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

What I need is to have every metric be in it's own column, and since some paragraphs have more lines than others, I can't do this in a step fashion. How would I tell VBA to loop through until a blank space between metrics is found and then place the next metric in the next column instead of all just in column A?

example:

EDIT: Need to separate each block of text in MS Word separated by a space (outlined in blue)

[image: word doc]

to this in excel

[image: output in excel]

That code above puts everything in column A, but I'd like each metric to be in it's own column.

Comment: Wow, I was sitting here trying to ascertain  why the last loop, then realized that is from my answer.  I just edited my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67221576/4851590) on your last question to remove the last loop, it is not needed.  Just need the `[a1].Resize(UBound(arr) + 1) = arr`  It will greatly speed up the code.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @ScottCraner makes sense, thanks for the update. Is what I'm asking in this post a simple edit or will it require a totally different structure in the code?

Comment: more of an addition than a different structure.  see below.

Comment: Had to make some changes in the testing.  try the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some counters to find how many columns and max rows, then use a second output variant array and load that:

```
Sub ParaCopy()
    Dim wApp As Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("D:\PERSONAL\This is a test.docx", ReadOnly:=True)

    Dim wPara As Word.Paragraph
    Dim arr() As Variant
    ReDim arr(1 To wDoc.Paragraphs.Count, 1 To 1)
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    
    Dim j As Long
    j = 1
    
    Dim k As Long
    k = 1
    
    Dim maxk As Long
    maxk = 0
    
    For Each wPara In wDoc.Paragraphs
        If wPara.Range.Words.Count > 1 Then
            
            arr(i, 1) = wPara.Range
            k = k + 1
            If maxk < k Then maxk = k
        Else
            arr(i, 1) = ""
            j = j + 1
            k = 1
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Next wPara
    
    Dim outArr() As Variant
    ReDim outArr(1 To maxk, 1 To j)
    
    k = 1
    j = 1
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 1) = "" Then
            j = j + 1
            k = 1
        Else
            outArr(k, j) = arr(i, 1)
            k = k + 1
        End If

    Next i
    
            [a1].Resize(UBound(outArr, 1), UBound(outArr, 2)) = outArr
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ParaCopy()
    Dim wApp As Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document, wPara As Word.Paragraph
    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("J:\HRIS Team\Data Dictionary.docx", ReadOnly:=True)
    
    Dim i As Long, c As Integer
    i = 1
    c = 1
    For Each wPara In wDoc.Paragraphs
        If wPara.Range.Words.Count > 1 Then
            Cells(i, c) = wPara.Range
            i = i + 1
        Else
            i = 1
            c = c + 1
        End If
    Next wPara
End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer, this works perfectly!